# Should i use Accelerometer or Gyroscope to measure angle of the z-axis

Tags: java, android, accelerometer, sensors, gyroscope

I am writing an An app in Android that needs to know the angle the rear camera is pointing with respect to the horizon and not with respect to it's last position. All of the definitions i have read for the compass and accelerometer don't say that i can do this. Is it at all possible to do this ?

Comment: Am not familiar, does the gyroscope have 2 or 3 axis?

Comment: Do you want the angle of the back camera with respect to magnetic north or the angle with respect to the surface of the earth?

Comment: Say for example you are at the sea, I need to be able to measure the angle between the horizon and the stars directly above it.for example using a sextant to measure the _altitude_ of a star

Answer (score 3):

You should use the Accelerometer.

The idea is the following, in a static camera, the only force (which is seen by the accelerometer) acting on the camera is gravity. This should be able to give you which direction is "down". What you would then need to do, is calculate the angle between the direction the camera is facing, (which is a constant, depending on which way your accelerometer is oriented) and the direction of gravity.

The dot product (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product) of the two vectors should give you the cosine of the vector (if the two vectors are unit vectors), then using arccos you should be able to get the angle in radians.

Since by definition, (true) horizon is 90º (pi/2 in radians) from down, you should subtract pi/2 from the result of the dot product, the result should be between -pi/2 and +pi/2.

A result of -x means the camera is facing "down" and making an angle of x with the horizon.
A result of +x means the camera is facing "up" and making an angle of x with the horizon.

Answer (score 2):

What you want to calculate is the angle between the surface of the screen and the surface of the earth (locally flat). This can be calculate using TYPE_GRAVITY or TYPE_ACCELEROMETER (less accurate). The angle is just the angle between the normal to the surface of the earth and the normal to the screen (z-value)

```
angle = (float) Math.acos(normalize z value);
```

where

```
normalize z value = event.values[2] / Math.sqrt(event.values[0] * event.values[0] + event.values[1] * event.values[1] + event.values[2] * event.values[2])
```

Answer (score 0):

if the camera is known to be static, then gravity could be used <strike>and this must be possible with an app since there's spirit level apps that do this</strike>.
[Cedric Garcias answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17052759/829755) and [Hoan Nguyens answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17052790/829755) above explain this in more detail.

if on the other hand the camera might be moving, then I think you have to track all the movements (using the gyroscope) and integrate them up from a point in time where the camera was fixed until the current time. that's probably quite challenging.

Comment: yes, if so, how do i know is the camera is facing parallel to the ground?

Comment: Doing this would mean i constantly have to track the change in angle , this i would expect to be bad for performance, i would like to know if there is any sensor that always knows it's position as opposed to calculating it based on the last position